# How do i fix this broken shading?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Could have been a simple auto-smooth related issue. God i would be grateful if it was, but it isn't.

My shading (despite being set on "smooth") looks funny. It's like a mix of smooth and flat shading.
Here's the vid - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPX8lmwHJxE

In the clip it's cloth sim, but the same happens on other geometry (doesn't matter it's created fully in this scene or downloaded from internet)

Here's a part of the table, still the same scene.
[image]

But thing is in solid mode it looks just fine and smooth, just as it should.

As shown in a video, auto-smooth is disabled and hard-edges are not present.

Also, i did change my gpu driver (to be specific, changed from game-ready to studio)

Just for a test, here's a simple shade smooth on geometry in this scene:
[image]

And here's in brand new scene:
[image]

Edit:
Worth mentioning that it looks fine in Cycles.

Edit:
Problem solved.
[image]

This little guy called "Bent Normals" was causing all these problems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello could you please share one simple object that has the problem? Like the last one your show?

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode*, select everything. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> to recalculate normals for the inside of an object). Sometimes this fixes it, so give it a try.

Also, try selecting everything, switching to face selection mode, and choosing *Shade Smooth* from the *Face* menu.

Next, try adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (after the *Cloth* modifier.) Your cloth object is fairly low-resolution and subdividing it may help.

**EDIT**

I looked at the actual file. I think you're viewing it in *Material Preview* mode. Try switching to *Rendered*. When I did the shading became nice and smooth.

If that doesn't work, make sure you're using the latest Blender release. They're putting out bug fixes all the time.

**EDIT**

@Redi4ka solved the problem.

*Bent Normals* in the Eevee Ambient Occlusion settings needed to be disabled/enabled.

Comment: Nothing seems to help, here's my .blend file. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/5DHAYv6ghw_sug

Comment: Tried recreating the issue in a new blend file.

Added lots of geometry and materials with bump maps applied. Result - as smooth as my screen's color depth let's it be.

Comment: Copied the file and deleted all the geometry in the scene as well as materials (didn't set "Fake user" on any, so one reload and all materials are gone). Problem is still here. 

Why it's always me to find a new, never seen before bug. God be merciful to me i am so close to do something very bad.

Comment: Ok, checking out your file now.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Thanks for the updates! If you don't mind my asking, how do you make those lovely keyboard icons here?

Comment: @Redi4ka I think I solved it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @SamuelSullins There's a [cheat sheet over at meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users)

Comment: God almighty i found the answer (with help from one cg discord server). All of this was caused by Bent Normals enabled in Eevee AO settings. Editing the main post rn. Thanks for contribution, glad someone tried to help.

Comment: Great! Glad you fixed it.